# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in php file

Tags: php, pdo

im getting this error on my refferal system, this is because registered account dont have any player / level , i mean they are empty. if i will fill with some info there, error **Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in** will disapear.

```
if(count([$getCharsINFO]))
{
    
    echo'<tr>
          <td>'.$i++.'</td>
          <td>'.$getCharsINFO['name'].'</td> //error here
          <td>'.$getCharsINFO['level'].'</td>'; // error here
    if($getChars['claimed']==1) echo '<td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled">'.$lang['collected'].'</button></td>';
    else {
    if($jsondataReferrals['level']<=$getCharsINFO['level'])
        echo '<td><form action="" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$getChars['registered'].'"><input id="submitBtn" type="submit" name="login" value="'.$lang['collect'].'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"/></td></form>';
    else echo '<td><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm disabled">'.$lang['not_yet'].'</button></td>';}
    echo'</tr>';
      $x++;

}
```

this is my function

```
function getCharData($id)
    {
        global $database;
        
        $stmt = $database->runQueryPlayer("SELECT * FROM player WHERE id=:id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $result;
    }
```

tried to add

```
if(empty($result)){
{
    echo "No Character";

}

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: `count([$getCharsINFO])` should not have brackets around the variable.

Comment: even without brakets, still the same. also if i remove brakets i get ** Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable**

Comment: You need to check if `$getCharsINFO` is not `FALSE` first.

Comment: try to check array_key_exist method to check if level key exist in returned data from query with an and operator in if condition where you used count.

Comment: remove count() as well